# error getting response using retrofit library

Tags: android, retrofit

i am using retrofit library to get check login credentials my php file containing the response is the following
login.php

```
 ...
 if ($user["invalid credentials"] != "true"){
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["id"] = $user["credentials"]["admin_id"];
    $response["username"] = $user["credentials"]["username"];
    $response["password"] = $user["credentials"]["password"];
    $response["email"] = $user["credentials"]["email"];
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Τα στοιχεία εισόδου είναι λάθος. Παρακαλώ ξαναπροσπάθησε.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
...
```

POJO class

```
 public class User {
      private int id;
      private String error, error_msg, username, email, password;

public String getError(){
    return this.error;
}

public String getError_msg(){
    return this.error_msg;
}

public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}
 }
```

my api service interface where the validateUser method has the username and the password the user enters
ApiService

```
   public interface ApiService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login/login.php/")
Call<User> validateUser(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
 }
```

and the checkLogin method where i create the Retrofit object

```
private void checkLogin(String username, String password){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Call<User> call = apiService.validateUser(username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                String email = response.body().getEmail();
                Log.d(debugTag, "email: " + email);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
 }
```

the error occurs when i am trying to get the email of a user(if the credentials are valid). I am getting a null pointer exception...is there a problem with my POJO class?

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>         11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>         E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem, PID: 21558
>         11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>         E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>         E/AndroidRuntime:at          com.votingsystem.tsiro.fragments.LoginFragment$4.onResponse(LoginFragment.java:175)
>          11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>           E/AndroidRuntime:at   retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
>   11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 11-09 22:51:06.152
>   21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 11-09
>   22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 11-09
>   22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 11-09
>   22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 11-09 22:51:06.152
>   21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11-09 22:51:06.152
>   21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>   11-09 22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566) 11-09
>   22:51:06.152 21558-21558/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post the stacktrace of the exception and the response of your webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i have managed to resolve the issue after digging into Retrofit 2.0.0 documentation. According to this guide https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9/ the HttpUrl.resolve() method creates links similar to . After that i removed the leading / from the partial url @POST("/login/login.php/") that overrides the last part of my BASE_URL and i added it to my BASE_URL and everything works like it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of retrofit i.e 2.0.0 ,it is allowing the full url support and create your pojo from this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)